# How to send user created articles to approval queue?

Tags: views, 7

I have an approval queue set up on a member's portal. The approval queues contain five content types that I created, one of them being 'Articles' and it is receiving daily RSS feeds. I'd like to also allow any user created articles to go there too.

The problem I have is that there is an Articles Adhoc page that was created in the views that is taking all of the user created articles.

I have disabled this page but the new articles still aren't going to the approval queues.

I checked around the Redaction module but I am unable to find anything on how to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you need but maybe you can achieve this using Rules. I've created a rule for nodes of type 'forum topic' and this is an example:

1. **Event:** Before saving content of type *your type*
2. **Conditions:** Data comparison -- Parameter: *Data to compare:* [node:is-new], *Data value:* true
3. **Actions:**

   - Conditional

     - If: User has role(s): Parameter: *User:* [node:author], Roles: *new*, Match roles: any

       - Set a data value: Parameter: *Data:* [node:status], *Value:* Unpublished
       - Show a message on the site: Parameter: *Message:* `your message`, *Message type:* Warning, *Repeat message:* false

---

The exported rule:

`{ "rules_forum_needs_approval" : {
    "LABEL" : "Forum needs approval",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_conditional", "rules_i18n" ],
    "ON" : { "node_presave--forum" : { "bundle" : "forum" } },
    "IF" : [ { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:is-new" ], "value" : 1 } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "CONDITIONAL" : [
          {
            "IF" : { "user_has_role" : {
                "account" : [ "node:author" ],
                "roles" : { "value" : { "14" : "14" } },
                "operation" : "OR"
              }
            },
            "DO" : [
              { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:status" ], "value" : "0" } },
              { "drupal_message" : {
                  "message" : "[node:title] needs approval.",
                  "type" : "warning",
                  "repeat" : 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}`